# Redirecting successfully but the Query isn't running in PHP

Tags: php, sql, redirect, mysqli

My sql query isn't running but the page successfully redirecting and data doesn't stored on data base. i'm using Wamp server.
Here is my query in user file .

```
$hashed = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$db->query("INSERT INTO `users`(`full_name`, `email`,    `password`, `permissions`) VALUES ('$name','$email', '$hashed', '$permission')");
$_SESSION['success_flash'] = 'User has been Registerd !';
header('Location: users.php');
```

this success flash display in my user page(successfully redirect) and data not insert into the database. can u help me to fix this. thank you very much..

Comment: what mysql error do you get? (when do you check for errors anyway?)

Comment: Use an `if/else` with proper error handling; you'll see why that is. Enable error reporting and `mysqli_error($db)` and tell us what those were.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the $db->query() does not stop the execution of the php script if the query fails. Normal program execution will continue.

It is left for you to check if the query was successful or not

Here is sample code to do that

```
if($db->affected_rows == -1)
{
    echo 'query fialed';
    echo $db->error;
}
else {
    echo 'query was ok';
}
```

Ps. To automatically stop page execution if a query fails,  you can use

```
mysqli_query($db, $query) or die("Error" . mysqli_error($db));
```

Comment: Mind you that to header("Location: somepage.php"); will not work if there is an echo before that because normal headers will be sent to the browser instead of a redirecting header